# How to prevent users from adding items to a list when the same user already has another item pending approval in that list?

Tags: 2013, list, workflow, permissions, approval-process

When a user adds an item to a list (called 'Conference List') an approval workflow is kicked off. During the approval process, the user should not be able to submit another item to the same list.

If rejected by the 'Approvers' group, the user is able to add an item to the list again. If approved, the user is not able to add an item to the list until they have added an item to a second list called 'Feedback'.

Are you able to advise firstly on how to prevent adding an item to a list if another is already pending review? Secondly, how a user can be suspended from adding an item to the list until they have submitted an item to a second 'Feedback' list?

Hope that makes sense. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need sp groups ( for contributors) and event receivers. Based on the item's condition, you add/remove user from the SP groups